# C# Ordering 2 lists randomly

Tags: c#

I have been trying to figure out how to randomly order two lists the same eg.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("RedHat");
list.Add("BlueHat");
list.Add("YellowHat");
List<image> list2 = new List<image>();
list.Add(Properties.Resources.RedHat);
list.Add(Properties.Resources.BlueHat);
list.Add(Properties.Resources.YellowHat);
```

now if i wanted to order these so that redhat and the redhat image stay aligned how may i do this?And is there a way to combine these lists and then shuffle using a dictionary or keyvalue pair or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ-fu version:

```
var rng = new Random();
var res = Enumerable.Zip(list, list2, (e1, e2) => new { e1, e2 })
    .OrderBy(x => rng.Next())
    .Aggregate(new { list1 = new List<string>(), list2 = new List<image>() },
    (lists, next) =>
    {
        lists.list1.Add(next.e1);
        lists.list2.Add(next.e2);
        return lists;
    });

list = res.list1;
list2 = res.list2;
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the two in an object:

```
class WrapperObject {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Resource { get; set; }
}
```

Add them to a list:

```
var list = new List<WrapperObject>();
list.Add(new WrapperObject() { 
             Name = "RedHat", 
             Resource = Properties.Resources.RedHat 
        });
```

..randomize:

```
var rnd = new Random();
list = list.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next(50)).ToList();
```

Comment: I could have used this could but the linq statement was "cleaner" because the lists i have were already made in a separate class

Answer (score 1):

Any specific reason why you want them in two lists, you could just create a list of keyvaluepairs like this:

```
        var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, image>> (); 
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, image>("RedHat", (Properties.Resources.RedHat)));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, image>("BlueHat", (Properties.Resources.BlueHat)));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, image>("YellowHat", (Properties.Resources.YellowHat)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the data in a `Tuple<,>` but if you had more than 2 elements its worth just creating an explicit class to store the data.

Tuple example:

```
List<Tuple<string, image>> list = new List<Tuple<string, image>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<string,image>("RedHat", Properties.Resources.RedHat));
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want:

```
var list1 = new List<string>
{
    "RedHat",
    "BlueHat",
    "YellowHat"
};

var list2 = new List<int>
{
    1,
    2,
    3
};

var combined = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => new { a, b }).Shuffle(new Random()).ToList();
list1 = combined.Select(i => i.a).ToList();
list2 = combined.Select(i => i.b).ToList();
```

You'll need the following extension method:

```
public static class ShuffleExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
    {
        T[] elements = source.ToArray();
        for (int i = elements.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int swapIndex = rng.Next(i + 1);
            yield return elements[swapIndex];
            elements[swapIndex] = elements[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First put the corresponding elements together, then apply random order:

```
var rnd = new Random();    
var ordered = list.Zip(list2, Tuple.Create).OrderBy(el => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

You can easily extract back the individual lists, if needed:

```
var ordered_list = ordered.Select(tuple => tuple.Item1).ToList();
var ordered_list2 = ordered.Select(tuple => tuple.Item2).ToList();
```